# Set ComBox to ComboBoxItem based on content

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox with comboboxitems hard-coded in the xaml, and I am trying to set the value of the combobox programatically based on a string value.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox  Name="comboCondition">
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem
</ComboBox>
```

Code that I would normally use when not using ComboBoxItems:

```
comboConditionValue.SelectedItem = "Item 1";
```

Of course this doesnt work when the combobox contains ComboBoxItems instead of being bound to a List. I am able to find the correct value like this:

```
foreach (var item in comboCondition.Items)
{
     if ((item as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString() == "Item 1")
         comboCondition.SelectedItem = item;
}
```

This is an messy and slow way to set the value, does anyone know any easier ways I can set the correct ComboBoxItem without cycling through the full list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You use a view model and bind your combo box that way (the preferred way)**

In your view code behind:

```
public myView()
{
this.DataContext = new myViewModel();
}
```

then in your myViewModel class, you have a property for the selected item:

```
private string _selectedItem;
public string SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        PropertyChangedEvent.Notify(this,"SelectedItem");
    }            
}
```

and then, in your view.xaml you bind to your combobox:

```
<ComboBox  Name="comboCondition" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: `comboCondition.Items.IndexOf("Item 1")` is `null` (yes "Item 1" exists in the Items collection. I assumed IndexOf would expect an object of type ComboBoxItem, not string. I have to admit that I am not familiar with ViewModel's and would prefer to avoid implementing one just for this small problem to which I have a work around, but I will do some reading and see what the advantages of that implementation are. If you remove or edit the second solution I can accept your answer

Comment: I've just learnt how to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on my existing class, so I have implemented your first suggestion in that manner... The second suggestion does not work however

Comment: ah yes, you are right about the second option.  I didn't check the code completely and neglected to remember about the object being needed.  I think you could've used something like: comboCondition.Items.IndexOf(comboCondition.Items.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Text == "Item 1")), where Text is the property that holds the display value.  But I'm glad you got the view model working, that is, by far, the preferred method when using WPF.